# Partition enumerable according to precedence

Tags: c#, linq

I'm receiving an `IEnumerable<TransactionLineDto>`. A `TransactionLineDto` can represent either an `Article` or a `Discount` which applies on an `Article`.

The order matters: a `Discount` applies only on the preceding articles until another discount is found.

There can be no discount at all (only `TransactionLineDto` representing `Article`).

There can be many discounts in one `IEnumerable<TransactionLineDto>`.

There cannot be more than 1 discount applied on an article.

Examples:

1. `Article1 -> Article2 -> Article3` means there are 3 articles without any discount.
2. `Article1 -> Article2 -> Discount1` means `Discount1` applies on both `Article1` and `Article2`
3. `Article1 -> Article2 -> Discount1 -> Article3 -> Discount2 -> Article4` means `Discount1` applies on `Article1` and `Article2`, `Discount2` on `Article3` and `Article4` has no discount

Now I need to "partition" these sequences to be able to know which discount applies on which article (article without discount must be discarded).

The expected output for the third example should be something like that: `(Discount1 -> Article1, Article2), (Discount2 -> Article3)`

How can I implement a datastructure/class that would modelize this behavior ? 
I thought about something like that (pay attention to the `???` that I'm unable to implement yet):

```
public class DiscountedTransaction : ILookup<TransactionLineDto, TransactionLineDto>
{
    private readonly TransactionDto _transaction;
    private readonly IEnumerable<DiscountDto> _allDiscounts;
    public DiscountedTransaction(TransactionDto transaction, IEnumerable<DiscountDto> allDiscounts)
    {
        _transaction = transaction;
        _allDiscounts = allDiscounts;
    }
    public IEnumerable<TransactionLineDto> this[TransactionLineDto key] => _transaction.TransactionLines
                                                                                       .Reverse<TransactionLineDto>()
                                                                                       .SkipWhile(l => l != key)
                                                                                       .Skip(1)
                                                                                       .TakeWhile(l => !IsDiscount(l));
    public int Count => _transaction.TransactionLines
                                    .Where(IsDiscount)
                                    .Count();
    public bool Contains(TransactionLineDto key) => _transaction.TransactionLines
                                                                .Where(IsDiscount)
                                                                .Contains(key);
    public IEnumerator<IGrouping<TransactionLineDto, TransactionLineDto>> GetEnumerator() => ???;
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
    private bool IsDiscount(TransactionLineDto line)
    {
        return _allDiscounts.Any(d => d.ID == line.Article);
    }
}
```

Is it a good approach or is it overkill ? (I mean is it possible to do that only with the pre-existing LINQ methods ?)

Comment: If possible I'd change the code that's generating these in the first place to create the proper associations.  And not to mix articles and discounts in the same DTO.

Comment: Can a collection of articles have multiple discounts applied to them?

Comment: This feels like it would be really easy without linq. Just loop through your transactions getting articles and putting them in a list. When you find a discount associate that list with that discount and then start a new list of articles. Repeat until done.

Comment: @juharr Unfortunately I receive these DTOs _as is_. My only friend to establish a link here is precedence.

Comment: @Servy No. There can be only one.

Comment: @Chris I share your feeling. However I always (personal opinion) try to solve these problems with a declarative approach first. I only use the imperative approach as a fallback solution.

Comment: @Spotted: Fair enough. Writing linq there looks like it would be messy compared to writing your own function to split it up but its your code, your choice what to do with it.

Comment: Can you show some details of the Dto classes? How do you get `allDiscounts` to pass in to this class?

Comment: @NetMage I could have shared them, however I thought it would bring nothing to my question. You can assume that `TransactionLineDto` has a `IsDiscount` property.

Comment: @Chris At the end of the day I took the approach proposed by Amy B where there is indeed some "imperative" code (`ToClusters` implementation) but encapsulated in an "declarative fashion" (as a LINQ extension method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static IEnumerable<List<T>> ToClusters(
  this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> endOfClusterCriteria)
{
  var result = List<T>();
  foreach(T item in source)
  {
    result.Add(item);
    if (endOfClusterCriteria(item))
    {
      yield return result;
      result = new List<T>(); 
    }
  }
}
```

later:

```
var lookup = transactionLines
  .ToClusters(line => line.IsDiscount())
  .Where(cluster => 2 <= cluster.Count) //discard the discounts with no articles
  .SelectMany(
    cluster => cluster.Take(cluster.Count - 1),
    (cluster, article) => new { Discount = cluster.Last(), Article = article })
  .ToLookup(
    pair => pair.Discount,
    pair => pair.Article
  ).ToList();
```

---

I find .SelectMany calls to be difficult to read, so here's the same with query comprehension:

```
var lookup = (
  from cluster in transactionLines.ToClusters(line => line.IsDiscount)
  where 2 <= cluster.Count
  from article in cluster.Take(cluster.Count - 1)
  select new { Discount = cluster.Last(), Article = article }
  ).ToLookup(pair => pair.Discount, pair => pair.Article);
```

Comment: "Modern" circa 2007.

Comment: With your solution, the `ToLookup` method yields an `ILookup<TransactionLineDto, IEnumerable<TransactionLineDto>>` although I would have expected (and needed) an`ILookup<TransactionLineDto, TransactionLineDto>`. How to do that ?

Comment: Right right, have to flatten into pairs before calling ToLookup.  Edit made.

Comment: Thank you for your insights. In the end I decided to implement a Custom `IGrouping` to keep the type safety and also to be able to flatten the nested IEnumerable and replace the call to `ToLookup` with: `GroupBy(cluster => cluster.Last(), cluster => cluster.Take(cluster.Count() - 1), (k, v) => new DiscountGrouping(k, v.SelectMany(t => t)))`.

Answer (score 1):

Using a (my favorite) custom extension method based on the APL scan operator (it is like `Aggregate` only it returns the intermediate results), you can scan across the reversed `IEnumerable` and gather the discount, then group by the discount.

The custom scan extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Scan<T, TResult>(this IEnumerable<T> src, TResult seed, Func<TResult, T, TResult> combine) {
    foreach (var s in src) {
        seed = combine(seed, s);
        yield return seed;
    }
}
```

Then you can `Scan` along the `IEnumerable` to gather the discount with each article, then group by the discount:

```
var discountPartitions = src.Reverse()
                            .Scan((discount: (TransactionLineDto)null, article: (TransactionLineDto)null),
                                  (daTuple, dto) => dto.IsDiscount ? (dto, (TransactionLineDto)null)
                                                                   : (daTuple.discount != null ? (daTuple.discount, dto) : daTuple)
                                 )
                            .Where(daTuple => daTuple.discount != null && daTuple.article != null)
                            .GroupBy(daTuple => daTuple.discount, daTuple => daTuple.article);
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. But in the end I decided to take the approach proposed by Amy B because I'm just finding it more clear (no offence intended against you).

Comment: @Spotted No problem, `Scan` is a quite complicated extension method, and like using `Aggregate`, takes a lot of getting used to and often isn't clearer than just doing looping.

Comment: @Spotted BTW, I like the `ToClusters` extension, I'll have to see how general I can make it.